# How to replace minimum value with some value in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android game. im using sqlite database. I have a table in which five score store. i want to calculate min of all score and replace min value with some other value? how can i achieve this?if there are more than one same score which are min i want replace only one?

Answer (score 1):

Fire the below query to get Min Value.

```
Cursor c = db.query(MY_DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { "min(" + KEY_ROWID + ")" }, null, null,null, null, null);
```

Here KEY_ROWID is your column name from which you want to find minimum value.

Get Minimum Value.

```
c.moveToFirst();  //ADD THIS!
int minValue = c.getInt(0);
```

After getting the minimum value update the value using query.

```
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put(KEY_ROWID, newValue);
db.update(MY_DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + minValue , null);
```

Comment: But it will replace all minimum values.